# Cant connect to jupyter localhost

Tags: jupyter-notebook, localhost

When I try localhost:8888 or 8889 it requires a password which I don't have, I found my link but after a while it says localhost refused to connect.

Comment: Maybe this [closed issue](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1979) will help you.

Comment: Today localhost refuses to connect I can't even see the page, how can I fix that

Comment: Did you get any error message in the development tools (console, network)?

Comment: No, I didn't but suddenly it connected 2 minutes ago. Thank you for your help !